# Access client x509 cert in twisted/thrift handler

Tags: python, ssl, twisted, thrift

Trying to figure out how to determine which client is connected in the protocol handler by accessing the x509 certificate. (Twisted, Thrift)

I found [twisted passing certificate to ssl handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968878/twisted-passing-certificate-to-ssl-handler) showing that its possible to call self.transport.getPeerCertificate in the Handler, but the transport layer doesn't appear to be available when using the thrift handler.  Is there a way to get the x509 cert in the handler when using thrift with twisted?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from OpenSSL import SSL
from twisted.internet import reactor, ssl
from thrift.transport import TTwisted
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol
from zope.interface import implements

from stwisted.test import TestStuff

class TestHandler:
    implements(TestStuff.Iface)

    def echo(self, instring):
        #Need to be able to see the clients x509 cert here
        return instring[::-1]

def Callback(connection, x509, errnum, errdepth, ok):
    if ok and errnum == 0:
        if errdepth == 0:
        try:
            print 'Cert: %s' % x509.get_subject()
        except:
            print 'Couldn\'t find appropriate tags in cert'
            return False
        return True
    else:
        print 'Invalid cert from subject: %s' % x509.get_subject()
        print 'Error no: %d' % errnum
        return False

def main():
    print 'Started'
    handler =  TestHandler()
    processor = TestStuff.Processor(handler)
    pfactory  = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolFactory()
    sfactory  = TTwisted.ThriftServerFactory(processor, protofactory)

    sslCtxFactory = ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory('server.key', 
                                                     'server.crt',
                                                     SSL.TLSv1_METHOD)

    ctx = sslCtxFactory.getContext()
    ctx.set_verify(
         SSL.VERIFY_PEER | SSL.VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT,
         Callback
    )

    ctx.load_verify_locations('ca_chain.crt')

    reactor.listenSSL(4444, sfactory, sslCtxFactory)

    print 'Starting Reactor'
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If you don't find an answer here, try posting to the Thrift user's mailing list.

Comment: What do you plan to do with the certificate?  Why does the handler need it?

Comment: For what it's worth, `self` in `self.transport.getPeerCertificate` is a `Protocol` instance, which, in this example, will be constructed by `sfactory`.  I'm not sure how Thrift propagates this object through to the handler though, or if there's some better way to obtain it.

Comment: The purpose of having access to the cert is to be able to use it to filter what can be available to the connected user.  For example, User A logs in, they should be able to see data X.  User B logs in, user B should not be able to see data X.

Comment: Glyph, Ill look into the thrift source a little more to see if I can find where the Protocol instance is used.

Comment: "*I'm not sure how Thrift propagates this object through to the handler though*" - the operative keywords are "abstraction" and "separation of concerns". The handler should not know about these details.

Comment: Another way to approach this would be to make the Thrift protocol implementation extensible in how it selects a handler to use.  The advantage of this is that you don't need to expose the protocol, the transport, or even the authentication scheme (ie, x509 certificates) to the handler (leaving it dedicated to your application logic).  Instead, you can do those protocol-y things in the protocol and express the outcome in your choice of handler.  This is basically how `twisted.cred` encourages you to do things.  cred support in thrift would probably give you a way forward.